# Resolve file paths in Jest

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I have a React based app in which I have a test file which I intend to run through Jest. The test requires importing classes from other files. The file that I import further imports other files and so on. The project has alias for many paths to lessen the typing when importing them (this is configured in Webpack).

When I run `jest` command in npm, I get an error saying 'Cannot find module ...`. How can I resolve file paths when running Jest? I can't mock the modules as these are custom modules which are required to run the test.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jest can handle this with `moduleNameMapper`
You can define the same aliases you have in webpack here too. This should make jest be able to resolve them.

From the documentation:

> And finally we just have the webpack alias left to handle. For that we
>   can make use of the moduleNameMapper option again.

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "modulePaths": ["/shared/vendor/modules"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx"],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "shared"],

    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react(.*)$": "<rootDir>/vendor/react-master$1",
      "^config$": "<rootDir>/configs/app-config.js",

      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files

Comment: I can't do that as there are lots of alias define as its a large project. And because dependencies are recursive, its hard to filter the ones which I need for my test.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to define them again for this to work. If you are using typescript you can also try to add the aliases in `paths` in your `tsconfig.json` but either way, you will need to define them all again for jest.

Comment: I am trying this out, but still getting errors. I have mentioned in `package.json`: `"moduleNameMapper":  { "react-common": C:\...react\common }`. I am importing a component located in `react/common/components` like `import {xyz} from 'react-common/components'` but it is not able to resolve this path. Is it not possible to combine mapped component paths defined in jest config with other paths that are child of the mapped path?

Comment: You need to use regex like in the example `"^react(.*)$": "<rootDir>/vendor/react-master$1",` to map children as well.

Answer (score 21):

You could add 1 line to your Jest config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

The configuration line above uses regex to map imports starting with the `@` character.

*Note:* (this above configuration code is assuming your source code is located in "project_root/src/"

Then, your import statements in your jest tests will look like this:

```
import {RepositoryController} from '@/controller/repository'
```

Which maps to `project_root/src/controller/repository`. This is much better then the relative path: `../../../src/controller/repository` my project would regularly require.

Comment: how do i configure multiple paths like below:
'import { NxDatepickerComponent } from '@xyz/ngx-ndbx/datefield/xyz-ngx-ndbx-datefield';'
'import { NX_DATE_FORMATS } from '@xyz/ngx-ndbx/datefield';' 
and used the follwoing in moduleMap:
"^@xyz/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@xyz/$1" but did not work. Would you mind pointing out the issue here? I'm gringding hours for this now

Comment: I think you're looking for modules. `export` and `import` statements in your source code to create modules. moduleMap for jest simply allows you to use the `@xyz` to find the directory but it requires modules for the import to be successful.

Answer (score 7):

you could as well try to add your aliased folder in moduleDirectories

```
"moduleDirectories": [
  "src",
  "node_modules"
]
```

I use this approach when I want to use absolute instead of relative imports like this:

```
import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent'
```

note: I have my components folder under /src

Answer (score 4):

Just a heads up for anyone else running into this: if you followed the Jest [getting started documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html), and came across the part that mentions:

> Generate a basic configuration file:
> Based on your project, Jest will ask you a few questions and will create a basic configuration file with a short description for each option

and followed that step, it will generate a `jest.config.js` file for you.

Subsequent Jest documentation (and SO posts) then refer to putting config options in your `package.json`, and if you go ahead and put your config changes there, (such as the ones suggested in this thread and others) Jest will ignore it and look at your `jest.config.js` instead.

(If you're like me) You'll then bang your head against the wall trying to figure out why the config options you've added aren't working even after following them step-by-step, only to later realize that the relatively empty `jest.config.js` file is squashing everything you've been trying to get to work in `package.json` which Jest is completely ignoring!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for webpack ^5:

Removing any jest config from package.json as @Eric above explained why, and adding this property to jest.config.json as @levibostian suggested above:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
},
```